# Script to copy cell and add date and time of when it was copied

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Need some help here guys.

I have a sheet with a script that updates every 5 minutes pulling data from API.

I have found a script to then copy one cell (D2) to another sheet in the first cell and than each one after when it runs.

```js
function tableCopy() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master");
  var values = sourceSheet.getRange("D2").getValues();

  var valuesLength = values.length;
  if (!valuesLength) return; 





  var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
  var requiredRows = lastRow + valuesLength - targetSheet.getMaxRows();
  if (requiredRows > 0) targetSheet.insertRowsAfter(lastRow, requiredRows);
    targetSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, valuesLength, values[0].length).setValues(values);



}
```

How can I also have the date and time of when the above script runs added to the column next to the column with the data it copied.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a `new Date()` to your values array.

```
function tableCopy() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master");
  var values = sourceSheet.getRange("D2").getValues();

  var valuesLength = values.length;
  if (!valuesLength) return; 

  var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
  var requiredRows = lastRow + valuesLength - targetSheet.getMaxRows();
  if (requiredRows > 0) targetSheet.insertRowsAfter(lastRow, requiredRows);

  values[0].push(new Date()); //Add Date to the 2D array.
  targetSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, valuesLength, values[0].length).setValues(values);


}
```

Comment: Awesome, that gives me the date in MM/DD/YYYY format in the next column how about adding the timestamp in HH:mm:ss? Thanks!

Comment: You should just be able to format the cell using the normal Google Sheets format menu? https://i.imgur.com/QCCdvDP.png. The Date object gives Sheets the date and time but by default sheets just shows the date.

Comment: That's what I was missing, duh. Thanks!!

Comment: No worries, happy to help. If this *or any answer* has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.